# Returning null after form submission

Tags: php, forms, null, isset

As a PHP beginner, I'm stuck with the following problem. I've made an HTML form, like this:

```
<form action="mailtest.php" method="post">
<p>First_name: </p><input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The problem is that, in the PHP-script ("mailtest.PHP"), `isset($_POST['first_name'])` always has value FALSE, even if I type in a first name before submitting the form. (And the same is true for all other form fields, which I haven't included in the above code.)

In other words, PHP somehow does not assign the submitted value (or an empty string, as the case my be) to variable `$_POST['first_name']`, and instead considers that `$_POST['first_name']` equals null... so something is clearly not connecting here. But what?

In the PHP code, I (for now) simply test whether $_POST['voornaam'] is null, like this:

```
if(!isset($_POST['first_name'])) {echo 'yes!';} else {echo 'no!';}
```

This always results in 'no!'

Comment: can you post your PHP code in short?

Comment: The code which has the bug is exactly the code you did not post here

Comment: I've edited my post to include the relevant PHP code.

Comment: Post the actual code you have, in your question, in order for anyone to be able to help you debug it

Comment: *"PHP somehow does not assign the submitted value"* Um.... **no, it's you.**

Comment: `$voornaam` ? --- `$first_name` ? Put up your real code `mailtest.php`.

Comment: Pretty much everything has been said. Let me add that if you want to check the value of a variable, you might want to temporary use a function such as `var_dump()`, it may be useful to find out exactly what you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check is `INVERSE` of what it should be   (if at all its voornaam and not first_name )

```
if(!isset($_POST['voornaam'])) {echo 'yes!';} else {echo 'no!';}
```

That means if `voornam` is `NOT` set then say `yes` and if it is set then say `no`

Should be

```
if(isset($_POST['voornaam'])) {echo 'yes!';} else {echo 'no!';}
```

Comment: @Hanky... Yes, you are of course correct. Will test further to see if I actually do or do not have a problem.

Comment: Damn, I was confused when I wrote this question... it does look like I simply tested the inverse condition (the exclamation mark). Yes, I'm tired. ;-) Will accept your answer later if confirmed. Also reading the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $_POST['voornaam']

to
$_POST['first_name']
```

is it ?

voornaam is the value that u ll insert in the textbox and u ll get in the $fname = $_POST['first_name'];//voornaam

***Just Use This***

```
if (isset($_POST))
{

  if ($_POST['first_name'] && $_POST['first_name'] !='' )
  {
     echo "yes, first_name was entered... ";

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!$_POST['voornaam']) {echo 'yes!';} else {echo 'no!';} 

remove the isset.!$_POST is equals to false. either true.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have get post data on mailtest.php file please try below code.

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['first_name'])) {echo 'yes!';} else {echo 'no!';}
```

use $_REQUEST for getting post variables in another page. because of you have set form action to mailtest.php. so please try above code on maintest.php file.